# What line is straight in "a straight shoulder"?

Tags: word-meaning

Pic 1:
[image]

In my native dialect, we say a curved/straight back, but not curved/straight shoulders.

**A curve is shown in pic 1. But I think this curve is for the back, not for the shoulders.**

Can you draw me a picture to show the curve of the shoulders in the left position, and the straight line of the shoulders in the right position?

As is shown pic 2, I think it's only possible to make the two shoulders form a straight line by shrugging your shoulders.

Pic 2:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We usually talk about "rounded" shoulders, rather than "curved" shoulders, but it means the same thing.

The rounding usually is visible best from the top, but I couldn't find any pictures of that, so I drew my own. In my pictures, the black is the head, viewed straight down from above. The green is the shoulders in healthy "straight" position. The red is the shoulders in an unhealthy "rounded" position.

[image: Hand-drawn image of shoulders in good and bad positions, shown from above]

Answer (score 1):

It just means straight above the line of your back, when viewed from the side.  Not pushed or slumped forward.

To be honest the first picture explains this far better than this answer.  It means with your shoulders in the position shown in pic 1.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put: everyday English does not make a strong distinction between the upper back and the shoulders.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/137255)

Comment: @mdewey I disagree. OP's issue basically boils down to their thinking "this curve is for the back, not for the shoulders," which is *true*. The first picture in the question shows a person with a rounded upper back. The issue is that, without invoking fitness/exercise physiology/anatomy jargon, idiomatic English doesn't really distinguish the shoulders and upper back. It's similar to how certain dialects of Spanish use the same word for lemons and limes.